# R: Matching rows by two columns

Tags: r, match

I am currently trying to figure out a vectorized way to match by two values in the same row. I have the following two simplified data frames:

```
# Dataframe 1: Displaying all my observations
df1 <- data.frame(c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8),
                  c("A", "B", "C", "D", "A", "B", "A", "C"), 
                  c("B", "E", "D", "A", "C", "A", "D", "A"))
colnames(df1) <- c("ID", "Number1", "Number2")

> df1
  ID Number1 Number2
1  1       A       B
2  2       B       E
3  3       C       D
4  4       D       A
5  5       A       C
6  6       B       A
7  7       A       D
8  8       C       A

# Dataframe 2: Matrix of observations I am interested in
df2 <- matrix(c("A", "B",
                "D", "A",
                "C", "B",
                "E", "D"),
              ncol = 2,
              byrow = TRUE)

> df2
     [,1] [,2]
[1,] "A"  "B" 
[2,] "D"  "A" 
[3,] "C"  "B" 
[4,] "E"  "D"
```

What I am trying to accomplish is to create a new column in df1 that states TRUE only if the exact combination is present in df2 (for example ID = 1 is equivalent to the first row in df2 because both of them consist of A and B). Additionally, if there is a shortcut, I would also like the status to be TRUE if the numbers are reversed, i.e. df1$Number1 matches df2[i,2] and df1$Number2 matches df2[i,1] (for example for ID = 7, the combination in df1 is A,D and in df2, the combination is D,A --> TRUE).

My desired output looks like this:

```
> df1
  ID Number1 Number2 Status
1  1       A       B   TRUE
2  2       B       E  FALSE
3  3       C       D  FALSE
4  4       D       A   TRUE
5  5       A       C  FALSE
6  6       B       A  TRUE
7  7       A       D  TRUE
8  8       C       A  FALSE
```

All I have gotten so far is this:

```
for (i in 1:nrow(df1)) {
  for (j in 1:nrow(df2)) {
    Status <- ifelse(df1$Number1[i] %in% df2[j,1] && 
                     df1$Number2[i] %in% df2[j,2], TRUE, FALSE)
    StatusComb[i,j] <- Status
  }
  df1$Status[i] <- ifelse(any(StatusComb[i,]) == TRUE, TRUE, FALSE)
}
```

It is really inefficient (you can clearly tell I am new to R) and does not look very nice either. I would appreciate any help!

Answer (score 0):

One method would be to `merge` things together.

Adapting your data, to account for reversed labels, I'll reverse `df2` on itself and rbind it:

```r
df2 <- rbind.data.frame(df2, df2[,c(2,1)])
colnames(df2) <- c("Number1", "Number2")
df2$a <- TRUE
df2
#   Number1 Number2    a
# 1       A       B TRUE
# 2       D       A TRUE
# 3       C       B TRUE
# 4       E       D TRUE
# 5       B       A TRUE
# 6       A       D TRUE
# 7       B       C TRUE
# 8       D       E TRUE
```

I added `a` so that it'll be merged in. From there:

```r
df3 <- merge(df1, df2, all.x = TRUE)
df3$a <- !is.na(df3$a)
df3[ order(df3$ID), ]
#   Number1 Number2 ID     a
# 1       A       B  1  TRUE
# 5       B       E  2 FALSE
# 7       C       D  3 FALSE
# 8       D       A  4  TRUE
# 2       A       C  5 FALSE
# 4       B       A  6  TRUE
# 3       A       D  7  TRUE
# 6       C       A  8 FALSE
```

If you look at it before `!is.na(df3$a)`, you'll see that the column is wholly `TRUE` and `NA` (the `NA` were not present in `df2`); if that is enough for you, then you can omit the middle step. The `order` step is just because row-order with `merge` is not assured (in fact I find it always inconveniently different). Since it was previously ordered by `ID`, I reverted to that, but it was entirely for aesthetics here to match your desired output.

Answer (score 0):

You could define the `combination` variable that you want to search for in alphabetical order as below:

```
combination <- apply(df2, 1, function(x) {
  paste(sort(x), collapse = '')
})
combination
[1] "AB" "AD" "BC" "DE"
```

And then mutate the Status field based on the concatenation of the Number field

```
library(dplyr)
df1 %>%
  rowwise() %>%
  mutate(S = paste(sort(c(Number1, Number2)), collapse = "")) %>%
  mutate(Status = ifelse(S %in% combination, TRUE, FALSE))
Source: local data frame [8 x 5]
Groups: <by row>

# A tibble: 8 x 5
     ID Number1 Number2 S     Status
  <dbl> <chr>   <chr>   <chr> <lgl> 
1     1 A       B       AB    TRUE  
2     2 B       E       BE    FALSE 
3     3 C       D       CD    FALSE 
4     4 D       A       AD    TRUE  
5     5 A       C       AC    FALSE 
6     6 B       A       AB    TRUE  
7     7 A       D       AD    TRUE  
8     8 C       A       AC    FALSE
```

## Data:

I set `stringsAsFactors = F` in the dataframe

```
df1 <- data.frame(c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8),
                    c("A", "B", "C", "D", "A", "B", "A", "C"), 
                    c("B", "E", "D", "A", "C", "A", "D", "A"), stringsAsFactors = F)
colnames(df1) <- c("ID", "Number1", "Number2")
```